# RabbitMQ Consumers disappear due to SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring-rabbit

After the SocketTimeoutException the consumers from the queue disappear and they don't come back. The messages in the queue are not lost. Using spring configurations:

```
spring.rabbitmq.connectionTimeoutInMillis=2000
spring.rabbitmq.autoRecoveryEnabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.topologyRecoveryEnabled=false
spring.rabbitmq.networkRecoveryIntervalInMillis=10000
spring.rabbitmq.heartbeatTimeoutInSeconds=5
spring.rabbitmq.concurrentNumberOfConsumers=2
spring.rabbitmq.maxNumberOfConsumers=10
```

Using default Connection Factory from Spring AMQP RabbitMQ connection. This is how the listener Bean is created.

```
//Listener Configuration
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    Consumer<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> configurer = c -> c.setShutdownTimeout(600); 
    factory.setContainerConfigurer(configurer);
    factory.setAdviceChain(workMessagesRetryInterceptor());
    return factory;
}

//Listener handler logic

try {

genericService.sendMessage(message);

} catch (Exception e) {

throw new CustomException();

} catch (RequeueableException e) {

throw new CustomException();

} catch (GenericException ge){

message.setRetry(Message.retry);
retryService.sendMessageToRetryQueue(message);

} catch (Throwable e) {

throw new CustomException();
}

// genericService.sendMessage(message) logic

try {

doSomething();

} catch (RequeueableException re){

throw re;

} catch (NonRequeueableException nre){

throw nre;

} catch (Throwable t){

throw new NonRequeueableException(t);

} finally {

//Handle finally 

}

//doSomething() logic

try  {

// This method call will cause SocketTimeoutException
// Then it will come to catch block
xUtil.callAPI(message);

} catch(final Throwable t) {

throw new RequeueableException(t);

}
```

Is there a way to make the consumers reappear?

Comment: You need to show your code and configuration. If you are using Spring (and its listener container), the container will reconnect and create a new consumer. If you are not using Spring, the amqp-client should automatically handle the outage. Edit the question, do not attempt to put code/config in a comment; comment that you have made the edit so I get a notification.

Comment: Made edit to question.

Comment: There is no such Boot property `spring.rabbitmq.autoRecoveryEnabled` (and it should be false for Spring anyway because it has its own recovery mechanism), or some of the others `concurrentNumberOfConsumers`. You need to show the beans where those properties are being used and exactly how you are consuming messages.

Comment: Added code representing how messages are being consumed.

Comment: You don't show any listeners and I don't see you using those properties - that container factory configuration will cause the containers to attempt to reconnect (and recreate consumers every 5 seconds). DEBUG logging should help; if you can't figure it out, post a minimal, complete, reproducible example someplace so I can see what you are doing wrong.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example